# многоконсольный вывод

Tags: python, python-3.x, вывод

Как можно реализовать многоконсольный вывод и вообще возможно ли это на python?
К примеру создается несколько окон и в каждое окно выводится своя информация

Comment: ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤвозможно

Comment: Во-первых зачем. Во-вторых существует библиотека tkinter для создания графических интерфейсов и с помощью неё можно создавать сколько угодно окон.

Comment: У процесса под Windows может быть не больше одного консольного окна. Поэтому, возьмите любую графическую библиотеку (tkinter, pyqt, что там еще есть) и создайте сколько вам нужно обычных окон.